# angular js, why my data don't visualize?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hello i'm trying to study angular, but is harder than i thought.
I only want to visualize some value of an array inside a controller, but in the browser seems to show anything.

here the code:

```
            <body ng-app="APP">
            <div ng-controller="theController">
                <b ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.title}}</b>
            </div>

            <script>
                    angular.module('APP',[])
                    .controller ('theController',['$scope',function($scope){
                    $scope.items[
                        {'title':'a','type':1},
                        {'title':'b','type':2},
                        {'title':'c','type':1},
                        {'title':'d','type':4}
                        ]
                }])
            </script>

            </body>
</html>
```

i just copy an existing tutorial, so WHY i can see anything inside the  tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

**From**:

```
 $scope.items[
             {'title':'a','type':1},
             {'title':'b','type':2},
             {'title':'c','type':1},
             {'title':'d','type':4}
             ]
```

**To**:

```
$scope.items = [
                {'title':'a','type':1},
                {'title':'b','type':2},
                {'title':'c','type':1},
                {'title':'d','type':4}
                ]
```

Working [`JsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/y1kqwq7j/3/)

Comment: :O ahaha was very simple

Answer (score 0):

**It is a very small syntax mistake No Worries** --Angular is very easy and magical indeed!

```js
 
angular.module('APP',[]) //app core module
               .controller ('theController',['$scope',function($scope){ //first controller to hold models
                $scope.items = [ //**Here = was missing; that was your minor mistake**//first model as array of objects
                    {'title':'a','type':1},
                    {'title':'b','type':2},
                    {'title':'c','type':1},
                    {'title':'d','type':4}
                    ]; //**semicolon was missing; putting is good practice**
            }]);//**semicolon was missing; putting is good practice**
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- app init and letting div to be controlled by our controller named as theController -->
<div ng-app='APP' ng-controller='theController'>
  <ol > 
    <!-- angular magical iteration on model, on items in this case -->
    <li ng-repeat='item in items'>
      Index:{{$index}} ==> {{item.title}} {{item.type}}
    <li>    
  </ol>
</div>
```

Happy Helping!